# Cloc (Count Lines of Code) different Header

Tags: linux, cloc

I create with cloc a csv file and used this file later in a Java Application.

This app runs on a linux vm, but I develope on a windows PC.

**The Problem:**

Cloc generate 2 different Header

**Command:**

```
cloc . --csv --quiet --by-file --unix
```

Testoutput via `Java Processbuilder.redirectOutput` or `> cloc.csv` in cmd

**Header Windows:**

```
language,filename,blank,comment,code,"http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.64  T=0.52 s (558.7 files/s, 29979.7 lines/s)"
Java,./b3-eos-ws/src/main/java/com/db/data/data.java,3,0,2048
```

**Header Linux:**

```
     100 files
     200 files
     300 files
Duplicate file check 327 files (278 known unique)
Unique:      100 files                                          
Unique:      200 files                                          
Counting:  100
Counting:  200
Counting:  300
language,filename,blank,comment,code,"http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.60  T=0.45 s (591.6 files/s, 34060.2 lines/s)"
Java,./b3-eos-ws/src/main/java/com/db/data/data.java,3,0,2048
```

Is there a way to hide the lines where cloc count the files ?
Or is the only way to remove this in my Java App ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. What is your `cloc` version? which operation system (version)?

Comment: @hek2mgl The version is 1.60 and the system linux(ubuntu), the version stands in the Header. I found out what the Problem was: I output the file with `Java` and with `> cloc.csv`...both times cloc output sometimes empty lines or other things that the format of each cloc file was different. I post my solution that the Output command was `--report-file=cloc.csv`, so the csv has always the same format without empty lines or sth else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I try it with

```
cloc . --csv --quiet --by-file --unix --report-file=cloc.csv
```

and this works instead of

`cloc . --csv --quiet --by-file --unix`

and save the file with Java `redirectOutput`

With this solution the csv has always this format without a blank line on the top or some output from cloc :

```
language,filename,blank,comment,code,"http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.60  T=0.44 s (605.4 files/s, 34856.5 lines/s)"
Java,./git/src/main/java/com/db/data/data.java,3,0,2048
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the **man page** (invaluable tool, btw) the switch **-q** will suppress intermediate output (anything but the summary).